# EKS console / terminal

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, eksctl

If I have cluster already setup in AWS EKS, is there a way to access the terminal and run the basic commands like `k get pods` / `services` etc. to get familiar with Kubernetes.

My doubt - Is the terminal accessible from within the AWS console itself, not from local machine / laptop terminal/command prompt connecting to AWS account.

Comment: use cloudshell for that https://aws.amazon.com/cloudshell/

Comment: Neither Kubernetes nor AWS has "a terminal", but you can run `kubectl` commands locally against the EKS cluster (given appropriate AWS credentials).